# Change Coordinates directely in the graphe

Tags: java, select, awt, coordinates, graphics2d

I have a Graphics2D and I draw on it some elements (circle for example)  I want to be able to select every circle and change its place in my graphe  (let's say change its coordinates in the Graphics2D)

Comment: Neither do I see a question nor an own approach.

Comment: My question is clear how can I be able to select an element in my graph and change its coordinates or its place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Oracle's tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/user.html

They describe how to recognize clicks within the Graphics2D. They also show how to move a single shape. You have to advance this approach a little bit in order to support multiple elements.